# Override a CSS line of a selector in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress

How to override this CSS

```
.fluentform-step {
    float: left;
    height: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

With

```
.fluentform-step {
    float: left;
    height: 1px;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

This code is loaded by a Form Plugin and I don't want to modify the original CSS stylesheet.

How can I replace that code, or in other words, hide or deactivate that overflow line?

I know I can use the Customizer but it wont replace it.

Comment: You need to explicitly specify a _different_ value for `overflow` in your own rule.

Comment: please try .fluentform-step {overflow: auto !important;}

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The issue is that I have that rule applied by default on the Plugin. And I need to somehow delete that "overflow: hidden" in order to make a div that's inside that parent sticky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this css :-

```
.fluentform-step {
float: left;
height: 1px;
padding: 3px;
overflow: unset !important;}
```

Comment: Good, but just one point, you don't need to add the rules that already exist. In this case you just need .fluentform-step { overflow: unset !important; } Regards.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The idea is to somehow delete that overflow: hidden for the selector. To be able to make a div sticky inside that parent.

Comment: if you found my answer is useful then please give vote to my answer.